# Excel 2016 - CONCAT ignores last cell

Tags: excel, concatenation

The following @CONCAT formula in Excel 2016 ignores the last cell.  It works fine in a new workbook but has an issue with a workbook with a lot of other @CONCAT formulas.

| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | E1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ; | TEXT HERE | ;;" | `<html code here>` | "; |

@CONCAT(A1,B1, C1, D1, E1)

The final double quotes and semicolon don't display.  All cells are set to General format.  I've changed the double quotes to ESC(34) in C1 and E1.  It works fine in C1 but doesn't display in E1.

It appears that the workbook is messed up somewhere since it works in a new workbook.

The expected output string should be ;TEXT HERE;;"";

Comment: How long is the html code?

Comment: Concat only allows up to 8,192 characters total.

Comment: `CONCAT()` and Excel 2016? Must be 2019 right?

Comment: and if you are using the `CONCATENATE()` it only has a 255 character limit.

Comment: Try: `=A1&B1&C1&D1&E1` instead.